# How to access a constructor of with default access (or package-default)

Tags: java, maven, reflection, access-modifiers

I'm trying to instantiate the constructor of a class which I imported as a Maven dependency via it's coordinates. The problem I have is that the particular constructor of this class, is invisible to me because it has no access modifier associated with it so it is default, meaning I can't access it from outside.

I know there is a way to access private methods via reflections, using getDeclaredMethod() method of class Method, but this doesn't work for constructors (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The class I'm trying to use is here:

```
public class DecisionTableBuilder {

   // Notice no access modifier here so it's package-default
   DecisionTableBuilder(Log log, File in, File out) {
      some stuff ...
   }

   // public constructor
   public DecisionTableBuilder() {}

   // Method 1
   public void compiler(File schema) {
      some stuff ...
   }

   // Method 2
   public void linker(File attribute) {
      some stuff ...
   }
}
```

Here is my toplevel in a separate project:

```
public class TopLevel {

   public void testDecisionTableBuilder() {

      // I get an error saying the constructor DecisionTableBuilder is not visible
      DecisionTableBuilder builder = new DecisionTableBuilder();

      // This works just fine, but no constructor...
      DecisionTableBuilder builder2;

      // This doesn't really work
      Method[] m = DecisionTableBuilder.class.getDeclaredMethods("DecisionTableBuilder", "Log", "File", "File");

   }
}
```

How can I access the Constructor and methods in a toplevel class which I created in a new project? Any assistance would be much appreciated

**EDIT**

```
public File graphDir;
public File outputDir;
public Log log;

Constructor<DecisionTableBuilder> constructor = DecisionTableBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Log.class,File.class,File.class);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
DecisionTableBuilder builder =constructor.newInstance(log, graphDir, outputDir);
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: You risk breaking third party code and/or leaving yourself very vulnerable to changes in their implementation by doing this sort of thing.

Comment: This is intented, I want this code to breake when the dependency class changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access constructors with `getDeclaredMethod` or `getDeclaredMethods`.  The Java reflection mechanism distinguishes between methods and constructors, and has separate methods for accessing them.

Try the [`getDeclaredConstructors` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-),

```
Constructor[] c = DecisionTableBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
```

or for a specific constructor, [`getDeclaredConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-).  Pass in the `Class` objects representing the parameter types, not the string names of the classes.

```
Constructor<DecisionTableBuilder> constructor =
    DecisionTableBuilder.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Log.class, File.class, File.class);
```

You will want to set it accessible and then call `newInstance` to create a `DecisionTableBuilder`.'

```
constructor.setAccessible(true);
DecisionTableBuilder dtb = constructor.newInstance(yourLog, inFile, outFile);
```

You'll of course need to `catch` the several exceptions that these reflection calls can throw.

Comment: Can you eleaborate what you mean when you say "Pass in the Class objects representing the parameter types, not the string names of the classes." Not really sure what to pass into getDeclaredConstructor() for parameter types? I thought it would just be the parameters the constrcutor took in?

Comment: As the last part of my answer shows, you can pass in the `Class` objects representing the types of the parameters.

Comment: Oh I see...but now how would I actually pass in these parameters, I see that this is just prototyping the constructor for creating a new newInstance of the constructor. Like would this even work: DecisionTableBuilder builder =constructor.newInstance(log, graphDir, outputDir); I modified my question to under EDIT

Comment: Yes; I've added more to my answer.